# Can I run android emulator smoothly on my virtual machine with nested virtualization turned on?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I tried running android emulator on my VM with ubuntu but when I open the emulator, I get a dialog box with the following message:

> Emulator is running using nested virtualization. This is not recommended. It may not work at all. And typically the performance is not quite good.

When I use the emulator, I get System UI not working message every 2 seconds. Is there a workaround or fix to this?
Should I just dual boot my computer to run the emulator?

At first, it asked me to turn on virtualization and when I turned on the nested virtualization, I got that message. I expected the emulator to run smoothly after enabling nested virtualization.

Comment: Were you ever able to make any progress here?